# Oracle JDBC Driver is slow working under Jboss Wildfly

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss, wildfly, java-17

I've encountered a problem where my fairly low-load Camel-based application being deployed to Jboss Wildfly AS executed SQL statements rather slowly compared to the same application running in JBoss EAP or as a Spring Boot Jar.

A single SQL call took 22 ms on average for the JBoss EAP / Spring Boot Jar running version. But under Wildfly AS it took 1-2 seconds. The difference is dramatic.

Later, I installed Jboss EAP and deployed my app there getting back 22 ms per call.

I enabled OJDBC tracing using `ojdbc11_g` module and the `-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true` setting. Analysing logs from the different environments, I didn't notice a particular operation inside the Oracle Driver to be long. All the operations executed in the Wildfly were x5, x10, and sometimes x20 longer than the corresponding ones being executed via Jar.

I'm still confused and have no clue what could be the reason for such a dramatic performance degradation under Wildfly.

Any ideas?

###### Versions used:

- OpenJDK 17.0.3 and Oracle JDK 17
- ojdbc11 v21.8.0.0
- Wildfly AS 26.1.2
- JBoss EAP 7.4.7

Comment: Slow.log — https://pastebin.com/82c5MXnk

Comment: Not so slow.log — https://pastebin.com/GyBADjb6